# UBO does not work correctly with OpenGL 4

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm having a hard time implementing light data with [UBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) support in my project, using OpenGL 4.0+.

I'm trying to use UBO for storing an array of light data of predefined max amount, and access it from fragment shader.

Here's the shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 tCoord;
smooth in vec4 vPosition;
smooth in vec4 vNormal;

// Diffuse texture.
uniform sampler2D sTexture0;

uniform vec4 vMatAmbientColor;
uniform vec4 vMatDiffuseColor;
uniform vec4 vMatSpecularColor;

out vec4 fragColor;

struct LightData
{
    int Type;
    vec3 Position;
    vec3 Direction;
    float Radius;
    float Attenuation;
    float CutOffAngle;
    vec4 AmbientColor;
    vec4 DiffuseColor;
    vec4 SpecularColor;
};

#define MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT 32

layout ( std140 ) uniform LightsList
{
    LightData Light[MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT];
    int LightsCount;
} Lights;

vec4 calculateLighting( LightData _light )
{
    vec4 _result = vec4( 0.0 );
    if( _light.Type == 1 ) // directional
    {
        _result = ( _light.AmbientColor * vMatAmbientColor ) + ( _light.DiffuseColor * vMatDiffuseColor * vec4( texture( sTexture0, tCoord ).rgba ) ) + ( _light.SpecularColor * vMatSpecularColor );
    }
    else
    if( _light.Type == 2 ) // point
    {
        float _attenuation = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + _light.Attenuation * pow( distance( vec4( _light.Position.xyz, 1.0 ), vPosition ), 2 ) );
        _result = ( _light.AmbientColor * vMatAmbientColor ) + ( ( _light.DiffuseColor * vMatDiffuseColor * vec4( texture( sTexture0, tCoord ).rgba ) ) + ( _light.SpecularColor * vMatSpecularColor ) ) * _attenuation;
    }
    else
    if( _light.Type == 3 ) // spot
    {
        float _attenuation = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + _light.Attenuation * pow( distance( vec4( _light.Position.xyz, 1.0 ), vPosition ), 2 ) );
        _result = ( _light.AmbientColor * vMatAmbientColor ) + ( ( _light.DiffuseColor + vMatDiffuseColor * texture( sTexture0, tCoord ) ) + ( _light.SpecularColor * vMatSpecularColor ) ) * _attenuation;
    }
    return _result;
}

void main( void )
{
    fragColor = vec4( Lights.LightsCount );
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < Lights.LightsCount; ++i )
    {
        fragColor += calculateLighting( Lights.Light[ i ] );
    }
}
```

NOTE: Nevermind the code in calculateLighting(), for now it's a dummy, but it should provide a minimal result of at least anything being calculated and returned.

In C++, I define fields' names like this:

```
const GLchar* k_sLightsListMemberNames[ 2 ] =
{
    "LightsList.Light[0].Type",
    "LightsList.LightsCount"
};
const GLchar* k_sLightDataMemberNames[ 9 ] =
{
    "LightsList.Light[0].Type",
    "LightsList.Light[0].Position",
    "LightsList.Light[0].Direction",
    "LightsList.Light[0].Radius",
    "LightsList.Light[0].Attenuation",
    "LightsList.Light[0].CutOffAngle",
    "LightsList.Light[0].AmbientColor",
    "LightsList.Light[0].DiffuseColor",
    "LightsList.Light[0].SpecularColor"
};
```

C++, setup code:

```
// Initialize light data storage.
if( m_iProgram && ( s_iLightDataBufferID == 0U ) )
{
    s_iLightDataBlockIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex( m_iProgram, "LightsList" );
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv( m_iProgram, s_iLightDataBlockIndex, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE, &s_iLightDataBufferSize );
    // Get indices for light data.
    glGetUniformIndices(
        m_iProgram,
        k_iLightsListMembersCount,
        k_sLightsListMemberNames,
        s_iLightsListMemberIndices
    );
    glGetUniformIndices(
        m_iProgram,
        k_iLightDataMembersCount,
        k_sLightDataMemberNames,
        s_iLightDataMemberIndices
    );
    if( s_iLightsListMemberIndices[ 0 ] != GL_INVALID_INDEX )
    {
        // Get offsets for members of LightsList.
        glGetActiveUniformsiv(
            m_iProgram,
            k_iLightsListMembersCount,
            s_iLightsListMemberIndices,
            GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET,
            s_iLightsListMemberOffsets
        );

        const GLchar* _lightsList2ndElementName[ 1 ] = { "LightsList.Light[1].Type" };
        GLuint _lightsList2ndElementIndex[ 1 ] = { GL_INVALID_INDEX };
        GLint _lightsList2ndElementOffset[ 1 ] = { 0 };
        glGetUniformIndices( m_iProgram, 1, _lightsList2ndElementName, _lightsList2ndElementIndex );
        glGetActiveUniformsiv( m_iProgram, 1, _lightsList2ndElementIndex, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, _lightsList2ndElementOffset );
        s_iLightsListArrayStride = _lightsList2ndElementOffset[ 0 ] - s_iLightsListMemberOffsets[ 0 ];

        glGetActiveUniformsiv(
            m_iProgram,
            k_iLightDataMembersCount,
            s_iLightDataMemberIndices,
            GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET,
            s_iLightDataMemberOffsets
        );
        // Create UBO.
        glGenBuffers( 1, &s_iLightDataBufferID );
        glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, s_iLightDataBufferID );
        glBufferData( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, s_iLightDataBufferSize, nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW );

        glUniformBlockBinding( m_iProgram, s_iLightDataBlockIndex, k_iLightDataUniformBlockBinding );
        // Bind data buffer to blocks.
        glBindBufferBase( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, k_iLightDataUniformBlockBinding, s_iLightDataBufferID );
        // Cleanup.
        glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0 );
    }
}
```

NOTE 2: The way I'm calculating array stride is only temporary, and it is like this only because for now I can't get glGetActiveUniformsiv() to properly return array stride for Light[] array. Right now it's of no importance.

C++, per-frame buffer update:

```
if( s_iLightDataBufferID != 0U )
{
    // Establish binding and mapping.
    glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, s_iLightDataBufferID );
    void* _map = glMapBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY );

    // Calculate and store lights count.
    unsigned int _lightsCount = 0;
    if( _maxCount == -1 )
    {
        _lightsCount = _lights.size();
    }
    else
    {
        _lightsCount = ( unsigned int )( _maxCount );
    }
    if( _lightsCount > k_iMaxAllowedLightSources )
    {
        _lightsCount = k_iMaxAllowedLightSources;
    }
    memcpy( _map + s_iLightsListMemberOffsets[ 1 ], &( _lightsCount ), sizeof( GLint ) );

    // Assemble lights data.
    for( unsigned int _lightIndex = 0; _lightIndex < _lightsCount; ++_lightIndex )
    {
        GLint _baseOffset = _lightIndex * s_iLightsListArrayStride;
        gizmo::scene::CGLightSceneObject* _nextLight = _lights[ _lightIndex ];
        // Type.
        GLint _type = _nextLight->getLightType();
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 0 ], &( _type ), sizeof( GLint ) );
        // Position.
        irr::core::vector3df _position = _nextLight->getAbsolutePosition();
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 1 ], &( _position.X ), sizeof( irr::core::vector3df ) );
        // Direction.
        irr::core::vector3df _direction = _nextLight->getAbsoluteRotation().rotationToDirection();
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 2 ], &( _direction.X ), sizeof( irr::core::vector3df ) );
        // Radius.
        GLfloat _radius = _nextLight->getAbsoluteScale().X;
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 3 ], &( _radius ), sizeof( GLfloat ) );
        // Attenuation.
        GLfloat _attenuation = _nextLight->getAttenuation();
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 4 ], &( _attenuation ), sizeof( GLfloat ) );
        // Cut-off angle.
        GLfloat _cutOffAngle = irr::core::degToRad( _nextLight->getCutOffAngle() );
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 5 ], &( _cutOffAngle ), sizeof( GLfloat ) );
        // Ambient color.
        GLfloat _ambientColor[ 4 ];
        _ambientColor[ 0 ] = _nextLight->getAmbientColor().getRed() / 255.0f;
        _ambientColor[ 1 ] = _nextLight->getAmbientColor().getGreen() / 255.0f;
        _ambientColor[ 2 ] = _nextLight->getAmbientColor().getBlue() / 255.0f;
        _ambientColor[ 3 ] = _nextLight->getAmbientColor().getAlpha() / 255.0f;
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 6 ], &( _ambientColor ), 4 * sizeof( GLfloat ) );
        // Diffuse color.
        GLfloat _diffuseColor[ 4 ];
        _diffuseColor[ 0 ] = _nextLight->getDiffuseColor().getRed() / 255.0f;
        _diffuseColor[ 1 ] = _nextLight->getDiffuseColor().getGreen() / 255.0f;
        _diffuseColor[ 2 ] = _nextLight->getDiffuseColor().getBlue() / 255.0f;
        _diffuseColor[ 3 ] = _nextLight->getDiffuseColor().getAlpha() / 255.0f;
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 7 ], &( _diffuseColor ), 4 * sizeof( GLfloat ) );
        // Specular color.
        GLfloat _specularColor[ 4 ];
        _specularColor[ 0 ] = _nextLight->getSpecularColor().getRed() / 255.0f;
        _specularColor[ 1 ] = _nextLight->getSpecularColor().getGreen() / 255.0f;
        _specularColor[ 2 ] = _nextLight->getSpecularColor().getBlue() / 255.0f;
        _specularColor[ 3 ] = _nextLight->getSpecularColor().getAlpha() / 255.0f;
        memcpy( _map + _baseOffset + s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[ 8 ], &( _specularColor ), 4 * sizeof( GLfloat ) );
    }

    // Clear binding.
    glUnmapBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER );
    glBindBuffer( GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0U );
}
```

During render, I just bind VAO with associated vertex and index buffers, and simply draw geometry using glDrawElements(), in GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP mode.

Block indices and offsets that are retrieved look like OK:

```
s_iLightsListMemberIndices[] = {8, 288};
s_iLightsListMemberOffsets[] = {0, 3584};
s_iLightDataMemberIndices[] = {8, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 0, 3, 7};
s_iLightDataMemberOffsets[] = {0, 16, 32, 44, 48, 52, 64, 80, 96};
```

Without lighting, the scene looks fine (simple texture() fetch in fragment shader). However, with 1 light added to scene, and with this shader used, the result is black screen.
Moreover, I've verified that Lights.LightsCount is equal to 0 (seems like non-initialized) in shader.

Comment: What is UBO? [[[[[[[[

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Uniform Buffer Object, I would assume. An [tag:opengl] thing.

Comment: Yes, that's a Uniform Buffer.

Comment: So you use `std140` layout, but you still want to query offsets manually. Why? The whole point of `std140` layout is that it is *standard*, and therefore predictable across all hardware. You don't have to query anything. You can design a C++ structure that matches the data layout in the GLSL struct.

Comment: That code exists because I've added std140 only later in the process of development, However, I actually intend to use a shared layout, if I manage to fix it - in any case, that is not the issue here - offsets search works in all cases and with all layout types, IIRC.

Comment: To get better granularity in graphics debugging I recommend a graphics debugger like gDEBugger or CodeXL. That way you will be able to analyze more than just the screen. FYI, I have no idea what your problem may be.